# ExtJS menu group, how to deselect with a remote button

Tags: javascript, extjs, menu

I have several nested menu radio groups and I was wondering how to uncheck the nested menu groups from the parent menu?

For example, I have a Ext.menu.Menu object with an item added that has a menu of another Ext.menu.Menu object. Each of these are in separate groups. I want to be able to click on another button to uncheck both of those groups.

The scenario I have is that I have these nested options available and a deselect button that I want to reset the options.

I am using ExtJS version 3.3.1.

The options are dynamically generated and multiple items share the same group. They are grouped by nested depth.

Example Menu:
None
Test > Still Testing > More Testing
Test Again > Continue Testing
Another Test

so None, Test, Test Again, and Another Test are in the group "level1"
Still Testing, Continue Testing are in the group "level2"
More Testing is in the group "level3".

I want the None button to uncheck level 2 and level 3. I am fine with it becoming checked for the level1 group.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably try to add a listener to your button in combination with the `cascade` function from the `Menu` class. `cascade` works its way down the container / component hierarchy, which seems like the sort of behaviour you want with your nested menus.

```
button.addListener("click", function () {
    topMenu.cascade( function () {
        //'this' refers to the current component as we cascade down.
        //check this components xtype
        if (this.getXType() === "menu") {
            //do the work you want to do
        }
    });
});
```

Without seeing any code, it's hard to explain much further than this.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you could just recursively navigate the menu, unchecking the menu items as you go.

Something like:

```
checkitem.on('checked', uncheckOthers);

uncheckOthers = function(checkItem) {
    var menu = checkItem.ownerCt;
    uncheckMenu(menu, checkItem);
}

uncheckMenu = function(menu, leaveItemAlone) {
    menu.items.each(function(item) {
        if (item !== leaveItemAlone && item.setChecked) {
            item.setChecked(false);
        }
        if (item.menu) {
            uncheckMenu(item.menu);
        }
    }
}
```